# DB Error: no such field in civicrm_api3() (when upgrading to 4.7.1) (Drupal)

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading from 4.6.12 to 4.7.1 (with Drupal 7.42), I get the following message when I go to CiviCRM :

CiviCRM_API3_Exception : DB Error: no such field dans civicrm_api3() (ligne 45 dans /home/parst/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php).

(in french)

... and cannot access to CiviCRM

Comment: Did you run in to any errors during the upgrade process (particularly whilst running the upgrade script) https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to run the Upgrade Script (step 11 of the CRMDOC)
When done, everything seems OK.
Thank you John, for reminding me.